# Display active session in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine total number of open/active connections in ms sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216007/how-to-determine-total-number-of-open-active-connections-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

In Oracle, there's a view called V$SESSION that lists all active sessions in database. Is there any similar view in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216007/how-to-determine-total-number-of-openactive-connections-in-ms-sql-server-2005#216020).

Answer (score 6):

Plain old `sp_who`.

Answer (score 3):

select * from sys.sysprocesses

can be used instead of v$session in oracle

http://silverlightedworld.blogspot.com/2009/04/vsession-for-oracle-and-sql-server.html

Regards
Renju
www.renjucool.co.nr