# Quickest method of finding unclosed SqlConnection's

Tags: asp.net, timeout, connection-timeout

I have an ASP.NET Web Application which is occassionally returning the following, irritating, error:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

My manager suspects this is because of an unclosed `SqlConnection` within the application. Therefore I'm currently manually checking through every single code file in the application to see if any connections were left open.

Is there a quicker solution to finding the root of this error?

Comment: how about find the open connections as you run your pages and see if they stay stable, or increasing ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216007/how-to-determine-total-number-of-open-active-connections-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: I'd check the server to see if there was a bunch of open connections and then enable profiler for a few minutes to see the last few commands issued by an open connection on the server.  Hopefully seeing the last commands will give you a clue where to look in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bunch of different options:

- Use Resharper and its "search with pattern" (also called "Structural Search"): http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/04/introducing-resharper-50-structural-search-and-replace/
- Write a miniature syntax tree walker for FxCop or Roslyn to perform the same search (basically, a new SqlConnection not disposed)
- Write a wrapper class for SqlConnection (more common than you might think), and track open/closed connections in there.
- Attach WinDbg to a "live" or ideally erroring application, and walk your heap objects back to where they are rooted from.
- Grab a proper profiler (SciTech is a neat one) that will give you call stacks for object creation.