# SQL Server timeout in recursive code

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a base class which implements my database connection.  I have a second class that inherits this base database class.  The second class has some recursion inside of it, where when evaluating it's value, it may instantiate another instance of the second class.  The recursion is only a few levels deep.  I am running everything single-threaded.

My code will run correctly for about 1 or 2 minutes, then I begin getting consistent errors: "Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool".

My base class has a destructor which calls the .Dispose() method on the database objects.  My second class has a destructor which closes the connection object in the base class.

My connection string to the database specifies a connection timeout = 0.

Any ideas as to why the code will work correctly for a few minutes and then begin timing out trying to connect to the database?  I'm baffled.

```
namespace BaseLib2
{
public class TSBase
{
    protected StreamWriter logFile;

    protected OleDbCommand queryCmd;
    protected OleDbCommand exeCmd;
    protected OleDbConnection connection;
    protected OleDbDataReader reader;
    public SqlConnection sqlconn;//used for BCP

    public TSBase()
    {

    }

    ~TSBase()
    {
        try
        {
            queryCmd.Dispose();
            exeCmd.Dispose();
            reader.Dispose();
            connection.Dispose();
            sqlconn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BaseLib2 destrutor:" + ex.Message);
        }
    }


    public void ConnectToDB()
    {
        string connString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=myserver;Database=mydb;Uid=myid;pwd=password;connection timeout=0";
        queryCmd = new OleDbCommand();
        exeCmd = new OleDbCommand();
        connection = new OleDbConnection(connString);            
        queryCmd.CommandTimeout = 60000;
        exeCmd.CommandTimeout = 60000;
        connection.Open();
        queryCmd.Connection = connection;
        exeCmd.Connection = connection;
        string sqlConnString = "server=dc2k8housql;database=mydb;Uid=myid;pwd=password;connection timeout=0";
        sqlconn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnString);
        sqlconn.Open();
    }
```

---

```
public class Expression : BaseLib2.TSBase 
{
private string ExpName;
private string ExpressionTxt;
private string sql;
private DateTime Contract_dt;
private DateTime Quote_dt;
private bool SaveToDB;
private string BaseSymbol;

public Expression(string expNameIn, DateTime contract_dtIn, DateTime quote_dtIn)
{
    ExpName = expNameIn;
    Contract_dt = contract_dtIn;
    Quote_dt = quote_dtIn;

    try
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectToDB();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in EXP constructor connecting to database." + ex.Message );
            throw new Exception("Error in EXP constructor connecting to database.");
        }
        //get expression text from database
        sql = "select expression, save_to_db, coalesce(base_symbol, '') as base_symbol from expressions where exp_name = " + DBI(ExpName);
        reader = ReadData(sql);
        if (reader.Read())//should only return 1 row
        {
            ExpressionTxt = reader[0].ToString();
            SaveToDB = bool.Parse(reader[1].ToString());
            BaseSymbol = reader[2].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in Expression constructor:" + ex.Message);
    }
}

~Expression()
{
    try
    {
        connection.Close();
        sqlconn.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
        sqlconn.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error in destructor:" + ex.Message);
    }
}

public double Eval()
{
    try
    {
        //check to see if there are any $RV in the expression
        if (ExpressionTxt.Contains("$RV("))
        {
            //parse and evaluate the $RV's                
            String[] split = ExpressionTxt.Split(("$".ToCharArray()));
            foreach (string s in split){
                Console.WriteLine("s=" + s);
                if (s.Length > 3)//make sure we have a string with a symbol in it
                {
                    //for each rv we find, create a new expression and evaluate it                                                
                    if (s.Substring(0, 3).Contains("RV"))
                    {
                        int pStart = s.IndexOf("(");
                        int pEnd = s.IndexOf(")");
                        string rvSymb = s.Substring(pStart + 1, pEnd - pStart - 1);
                        System.Console.WriteLine(rvSymb);
                        Expression oExp = new Expression(rvSymb, Contract_dt, Quote_dt);
                        double rVal = oExp.Eval();//recursive call
                        oExp = null;
                        ExpressionTxt = ExpressionTxt.Replace("$RV(" + rvSymb + ")", rVal.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //replace SV values in formula
        if (ExpressionTxt.Contains("$SV("))
        {
            //find symbols in $SV brackets and collect contract dates
            String[] split = ExpressionTxt.Split (("$".ToCharArray()));
            foreach (string s in split)
            {
                if (s.Length > 3)
                {//make sure we have a symbol
                    if (s.Substring(0, 3).Contains("SV"))
                    {
                        int pStart = s.IndexOf("(");
                        int pEnd = s.IndexOf(")");
                        string svSymb = s.Substring(pStart + 1, pEnd - pStart - 1);
                        System.Console.WriteLine("sv=" + svSymb);
                        //replace $SV with numerical values
                        double sVal = GetQuoteValue(svSymb);
                        ExpressionTxt = ExpressionTxt.Replace("$SV(" + svSymb + ")", sVal.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }           
        //evaluate 
        double ret = Evaluate(ExpressionTxt);
        Console.WriteLine(ExpName + "=" + ret.ToString());
        if (SaveToDB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ExpName + " cd:" + Contract_dt.ToShortDateString() + " qd:" + Quote_dt.ToShortDateString() + ": saving to db...");
            sql = "delete from exp_quotes where exp_name = " + DBI(ExpName ) ;
            sql = sql + " and contract_dt = " + DBI(Contract_dt.ToShortDateString());
            sql = sql + " and quote_dt = " + DBI(Quote_dt.ToShortDateString());
            WriteData(sql);
            sql = "insert into exp_quotes(exp_name, contract_dt, quote_dt, calculated_dt, price) values(";
            sql = sql + DBI(ExpName ) + "," + DBI(Contract_dt.ToShortDateString()) + "," + DBI(Quote_dt.ToShortDateString());
            sql = sql + ", getdate(), " + ret + ")";
            WriteData(sql);
        }
        connection.Close();//after we evaluate, close down the connection
        connection.Dispose();
        return ret;
        //return value
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("exp:" + ExpName + " cd:" + Contract_dt.ToShortDateString() + " qd:" + Quote_dt.ToShortDateString() + " = " + ex.Message);
    }        
    return 0;
}

private double GetQuoteValue(string symbIn)
{
    double ret = 0;
    sql = "select close_val from prices_union_all_vw where symbol = " + DBI(symbIn) + " and contract_dt = " + DBI(Contract_dt.ToShortDateString()) + " and quote_dt = " + DBI(Quote_dt.ToShortDateString());
    reader = ReadData(sql);
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        ret = Double.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
        reader.Close();
    }
    else
    {//we didn't get a record for the specific quote date, try again using the mostrecent view
        sql = "select close_val from prices_union_all_mostrecent_vw where symbol = " + DBI(symbIn) + " and contract_dt = " + DBI(Contract_dt.ToShortDateString());
        reader = ReadData(sql);
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            ret = Double.Parse(reader[0].ToString());                
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    return ret;
}

private static double Evaluate(string expression)
{
    var loDataTable = new DataTable();
    var loDataColumn = new DataColumn("Eval", typeof(double), expression);
    loDataTable.Columns.Add(loDataColumn);
    loDataTable.Rows.Add(0);
    return (double)(loDataTable.Rows[0]["Eval"]);
}
```

Comment: Might Provide some code please to help visualize what you are doing.

Comment: One thing to do is possibly to check your ConnectionState during your recursion and make sure the connection is still available.

Comment: Your finalizer is incorrect by the way, you should not dispose those other objects. Basically, remove the finalizer altogether.

Comment: string concatenation with += is not efficent, always use stringbuilder or string.format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are exhausting your available pool of connections because you are creating a connection to the database for every Expression and sub-Expression that you parse, and they are not being cleaned up in time to be re-used.

**Solution:**  Do not make connections recursively, or iteratively, or whatever.  Make one for one purpose and just use it.  And if you need to release a connection in-time for you to re-use it, do *NOT* rely on class destructors, because they do not run when you want them to.

In general, classes that try to allocate limited external resources (like connections) implicitly in their Initializers should be pretty static objects, and you certainly do not normally want to inherit them in a class that is intended to create objects as dynamically as a parser.

Comment: using a single connection object and passing it worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried extending the timeout period?
Add a big timeout to the connection string like "Connect Timeout=1800". This usually helps me when I get such messages.

The other thing you can see is if you can improve the query more.

Comment: The query isn't the problem, its the actual opening of the connection to the database that is timing out.  I have the server set to default connection timeout of zero.  I tried modifying the timeout to 1800 in the connection string but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You might check your Max connection setting for the database. Also check how many active connections are open when new connection attempts start to time out.

[How to determine total number of open/active connections in ms sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216007/how-to-determine-total-number-of-open-active-connections-in-ms-sql-server-2005)